# Transfer to Bitcoin ABC wallet is waiting for full download

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I'm fairly new to cryptocurrency and decided to transfer some of my LTC to BCC using a Bitcoin ABC wallet on my MacBook. To test the wallet I already transfered 1 BCC to the generated adres. I was not aware that this wallet had to download the whole blockchain before I could use the wallet. Now I'm unable to reach this one BCC... Is there any way around downloading the whole blockchain to my MacBook? I'm at 2% increase per hour, around two days waiting for me??

Comment: You can't transfer LTC directly to BCC; is this a typo or did you trade it on an exchange?

Comment: Trade through USD to BCC! That was no problem! I trade on Kraken or Bitfinex.

Answer (score -1):

You could use wallet software that does not require downloading of the blockchain, in the same way [electrum.org](http://electrum.org) does for Bitcoin.

Comment: then import the private key into it

Comment: I guess, but really an HD wallet BIP39 mnemonic is better

Comment: -1. Electrum does not support BCH. Download [Electron Cash](https://electroncash.org/)

Comment: I worded it wrong, I meant electrum as an example of such software. Not the one they would need to use.